# Gulp Concat + Uglify order JS error

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-concat

I'm trying to concat and uglify javascript files in a specific order. When i disable uglify it works well as i order. But when i turn on uglify, the JS order is ignored. What am i doing wrong?

**Script_1.js**

```
let script_one = () => {
   console.log(1);
};
```

**Script_2.js**

```
let script_two = () => {
   console.log(2);
};
```

**Gulp Task**

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src(['js/Script1.js', 'js/Script2.js'])
      .pipe(rigger())
      .pipe(concat('main.js'))
      .pipe(babel({presets: ['env']}))
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});
```

**Output**

> var script_two=function(){console.log(2)};var script_one=function(){console.log(1)};

**Expected Output**

> var script_one=function(){console.log(1)};var script_two=function(){console.log(2)};

**Output without Uglify**

```
  var script_one = function(){
     console.log(1)
  };
  var script_two = function(){
     console.log(2)
  };
```

Thanks!!